# Equivalent definitions of fractional ideals

Tags: commutative-algebra, ideals

Let $R$ be an integral domain and $K$ its field of fractions. The usual definition of fractional ideal $I$ ($I$ is an $R$-submodule of $K$) is that for some nonzero $r\in R$ we have $rI\subset R$, and the intuition is that $r$ clears the denominators in $I$. But I came across another definition: there are units $z$, $u\in K$ such that $zR\subset I\subset uR$. What is the relationship between these two definitions? Which one is "normally" used? What is the intuition for the second case?

Comment: What do you mean by $u$ unit in $K$? Mind that if you mean that $u$ must be invertible in $R$ then $uR=R$ and your second definition is clearly false.

Comment: I took this second definition from the book Algebra,Vol.2 by P.M.Cohn,chapter Dedekind domains,page 321 first paragraph.If the book is unavailable to you,I'll rewrite the paragraph word for word here.

Comment: Ok, but you still haven't told me what a unit in $K$ is.

Comment: He takes z,u from K^x;perhaps he means all nonzero elements?

Comment: I explained the thing in an answer below. I asked for the correct definition of "unit in $K$" because at least in the case where $K$ is an algebraic extension of $\Bbb Q$ the name "unit" is traditionally reserved to the elements in the group $R^\times$, *not* $K^\times$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $I$ be a fractional ideal according to definition $1$ which I believe includes also $I\neq(0)$.

Pick any $0\neq z\in I$ then $z\in K^\times$ and $zR\subset I$. Also, from $rI\subset R$ you get $I\subset\frac1rR$ and $u=\frac1r\in K^\times$.

If, on the other hand, you start from definition $2$, from $zR\subset I$ you get $z\cdot1\in I$ so that $I\neq(0)$. Next, write $u=\frac ab$ with $a$ and $b\in R$. Thus $I\subset uR=\frac abR$ implies $bI\subset aR\subset R$ which is the requirement of definition $1$ with $r=b$.